# Migration Assistant problem

Tags: time-machine, backup, ssd, migration

Replacing a failing HD with an SSD in an early 2011 MBP 13".  Made a Time Machine backup to an external USB HD with original disk, installed the SSD, installed OS X from the install DVD that came with the machine.  Success so far, when I try to run Migration Assistant to restore files it does not recognize the external drive as a source option, instead only offering 2 Time Capsule drives as potential sources.  With the external drive connected, Finder sees it and sees a folder 2015-06-22, xxxx.  This folder contains 3 sub folders with the backup files in them.  They are just invisible to Migration Assistant with the new SSD installed, even though recognized and seen by Finder.  I suspect some kind of conflict with UUID's between the old drive and the new drive, but I'm at a loss as how to diagnose and fix the problem and then restore my old files.  Any pointers, ideas or a full blown solution would be greatly appreciated

Comment: did you try the Terminal "diskutil list" to take a look at that drive.

Comment: I will as soon as I can pry it back out of my wife's hands - it is her laptop and she was in serious withdrawal while I was buying and changing out both the SATA cable and the SSD